# Django - Removing extraneous unicode symbols from geraldo reports

Tags: python, django, unicode, reportlab

I am using geraldo/reportlab to generate part reports on my database. Reportlab only lets me perform one queryset at a time (as I understand it.) As a result, certain aspects of my report are pulled out of ManyToMany fields and ForeignKeys.

For example, class band_detail in reports.py:

```
ObjectValue(attribute_name='number', left = 9*cm, get_value=lambda instance: Drawing.objects.filter(number=DrawingRevision.objects.filter(part__id=instance.id).values('drawing')).values_list('number', flat=True))
```

This displays as:

```
[u'1', u'2', u'3']
```

...and so on. I don't know how to get rid of the unicode symbol "u." I can't iterate over my lambda function in ObjectValue. I tried overriding geraldo classes and definitions such as do_before_generate(), but had no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[s.encode() for s in
 ObjectValue(attribute_name='number',
            left = 9*cm, 
            get_value=lambda instance:
               Drawing.objects.filter(number=DrawingRevision.objects
                                             .filter(part__id=instance.id)
                                             .values('drawing')
                                     ).values_list('number', flat=True)
           )
]
```

or

```
ObjectValue(attribute_name='number',
            left = 9*cm, 
            get_value=lambda instance:
            [ n.encode() for n in
               Drawing.objects.filter(number=DrawingRevision.objects
                                             .filter(part__id=instance.id)
                                             .values('drawing')
                                     ).values_list('number', flat=True)
            ]
           )
```

this should give you:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't iterate through an ObjectValue. I can, however, iterate through band_detail.elements within geraldo, where elements are what is returned by ObjectValue. The problem is, when I go to iterate through band_detail.elements, object types are None. For some reason they haven't been created by the time geraldo hits the process do_after_generate. Any ideas on what function to use in geraldo so that I can iterate through my elements?

Comment: Why not applying encode function on value_list inside the lambda?

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work. I didn't get an error, but everything stayed the same. I also found out that I could add a display_format attribute to my ObjectValue, but when I tried to encode that using display_format="%s".encode() and/or display_format=unicode("%s"), that didn't work either.

Comment: question: where is `[u'1', u'2', u'3']` displayed? in the report?